# Private military activity

Tags: international, laws-of-war, sovereignty, military

Is there any country that would legally allow a private military organization to take part in a military conflict outside of its own borders?

For example, a private military agency established in country A takes part in a conflict between B and C in the territories of both B and C, but not in A's.

Comment: An obvious example is the United States hiring "security contractors" such as Blackwater for the war in Iraq.

Comment: Why do you think country A would have any say or care in the matter?

Comment: People fighting for a private military organisation such as you have described, in the circumstances you have described, would be defined as mercenaries under the laws of war, and potentially as unlawful combatants: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mercenary&oldid=687015301#Laws_of_war

Comment: @NateEldredge in the case of Blackwater, the conflict is between A and B, so your example does not meet the criteria described in the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Blackwater (later named "Xe Services" and now "Academi") was established in the USA, and the USA was at war with Iraq from 2003-2011. Blackwater therefore is *not* an example that matches the OP's scenario.

Comment: @feetwet It's against the law in France, at least. http://legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070719&idArticle=LEGIARTI000006418746&dateTexte=20151118

Comment: I seem to recall some news about private groups going in to various places to fight ISIS. If someone can dig that up, might be a better fit for an example.

Comment: @feetwet In the US, it is a [federal crime](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/960) for any person within the US to launch a military expedition against a country with which the US is at peace.

Comment: This question is too broad - there are currently 192 member states of the UN, all with different legal systems. The conduct described may be specifically illegal in some and probably includes activities that would be illegal in most, however, unless someone is willing to enumerate the relevant laws of all 192 this question has no answer.